# Обработать ситуацию, если нет пользователя в БД

Tags: c#, asp.net, исключения

Получаю пользователя. Хочу обработать вариант, что его нет в базе (с таким Id). Как лучше сделать:

Так?

```
/// <summary>
/// Получить инфо о клиенте для карточки
/// </summary>
[Route("api/clients/{id}/{adPush}")]
public object Get(long id, bool adPush)
{
    return Ok(mng.GetAsync(id, adPush));
}


public Client GetAsync(long id, bool adPush)
{   
    try
    {
        return rep.GetAsync(id);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new HttpException("Нет клиента с таким Id или проблемы с доступом к серверу");
    }
}
```

В этом случае приложение аварийно остановится и клиент (мобильный телефон), как я понимаю, получит HTTP ответ. 
С какой ошибкой?

или так?

```
/// <summary>
/// Получить инфо о клиенте для карточки
/// </summary>
[Route("api/clients/{id}/{adPush}")]
public object Get(long id, bool adPush)
{
    if (mng.GetAsync(id, adPush)) == null)
           return BadRequest();
    return Ok(mng.GetAsync(id, adPush));
}


public Client GetAsync(long id, bool adPush)
{   
    try
    {
        return rep.GetAsync(id);
    }
    catch // если нет клиента
    {
         return null; 
    }
}
ещё вариант:
public Client GetAsync(long id, bool adPush)
{   
    if (rep.GetAsync(id) == null)
        return null;
    return rep.GetAsync(id);
}
```

видимо так лучше, т.к. не вызывается ресурсоёмкое исключение

Какую ошибку возвращать на клиент? 400? Если трактовать так, что неправильный синтаксис в запросе. Но неверный id - это неправильный синатксис? 
Или 500? С той позиции что сервер не может дать что мы запрашиваем
Или ещё какой-то код состояния?

UPD
Спасибо за ответы

Я решил пойти другим путём - не бросать исключения, а передавать клиенту состояния HTTP

У меня получились такие CRUD операции:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Зарегистрировать клиента
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<object> Post()
    {
        if (await mng.CreateAsync(form["name"], form["phone"]))
            return Ok(true);

        return BadRequest("Не удалось создать клиента");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получить инфо о клиенте для карточки
    /// </summary>
    [Route("api/clients/{id}/{adPush}")]
    public object Get(long id, bool adPush)
    {
        Client client = mng.GetAsync(id, adPush);
        if (client == null)
            return BadRequest("Нет клиента с таким Id");

        return Ok(client);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Редактировать инфо клиента
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<object> Update()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(form["id"]);
        string name = form["name"];
        bool adPush = Convert.ToBoolean(form["adPush"]);
        if (await mng.UpdateAsync(id, name, adPush))
            return Ok(true);

        return BadRequest("Нет клиента с таким Id");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Удалить клиента
    /// </summary>
    [HttpDelete]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete()
    {
        if (await mng.DeleteAsync(Convert.ToInt32(ServiceUtil.Request.Form["id"])))
            return Ok(true);

        return BadRequest("Нет клиента с таким Id");
    }



    public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(string name, string phone)
    {
        try
        {
            await rep.CreateAsync(GetInstance(name, phone));
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Client GetAsync(long id, bool adPush)
    { 
        return rep.GetAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(long id, string name, bool adPush) // adPush - позже
    {
        Client client = rep.GetAsync(id);
        if (client == null)
            return false;

        client.Name = name;
        try
        {
            await rep.UpdateAsync(client);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpException(500, "Не удалось обновить клиента, проблемы с каналом или сервером");
        }
        return true;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(long id)
    {
        Client client = rep.GetAsync(id);
        if (client == null)
            return false;

        try
        {
            await rep.DeleteAsync(client);
        } 
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpException(500, "Не удалось удалить клиента, проблемы с подключением или сервером");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Т.е. улучшил семантику - теперь бизнесовые методы возвращают true/false своего результата. Но получается такой микс - примешались исключения. Не хотелось бы их бросать. 
Сейчас есть идея возвращать не true/false, а enum, например

```
enum CRUDResult {NoEntityWithId, NoConnectionOrServerProblems}
```

- соотв. нет сущности с таким Id, проблема с подключением или сервером. При возникновении других исключительных ситуаций этот enum будет расширяться. Контроллер в зависимости от значения enum выбросит нужный статус

Нормально так?

Ещё вопрос - нормально ли в catch бросать не exception, а делать что-то другое - например вернуть false?

Comment: Что из себя представляет "пользователь" в данном случае? Того, кто работает с сервисом? Тогда возвращайте ошибку 401 - Unathorized или 403 - Forbidden. Или это просто некие данные? Тогда возвращайте 404 - Not found.

Comment: _"Нет клиента с таким Id или проблемы с доступом к серверу"_ - это две разные ошибки. Соответственно, должны возвращаться разные http-коды в ответ.

Comment: _приложение аварийно остановится_ - не обязательно. Зависит от того, как оно написано.

Comment: Для чего параметр `adPush`? Могли бы убрать его перед написанием вопроса. Или уточните, важен ли он.

Comment: Во-втором и третьем вариантах вы по два раза вызываете `GetAsync`. Данные обычно получаются из БД, т. е. весьма затратны по времени. Бить за такое надо.

Comment: _получит HTTP ответ. С какой ошибкой?_ - блин, ну запустите приложение и проверьте. И нет, мобильный клиент для этого совсем не нужен.

Comment: Не возвращайте `object`. Возвращайте `IActionResult` в общем случае. Или типы, его реализующие, если можно указать более конкретно.

Comment: Ответьте, пожалуйста, на последний вопрос?

Comment: Одна тема - один вопрос. Не задавайте несколько вопросов в одном сообщени.

Answer (score 0):

На этот вопрос надо давать развёрнутый ответ, потому что он затрагивает несколько пластов.

Начнём с HTTP-статуса. Ситуации *ресурс не найден* соответствует статус *404*. Его и будем возвращать.

Как это сделать? Должен ли метод `GetUser` возвращать `null`, который мы обработаем в контроллере? Роберт Мартин в своей книге «Чистый код» от такого предостерегает. Я с ним согласен. Правильным будет, если `GetUser` вернёт пользователя с указанным идентификатором, а в случае его отсутствия возбудит исключение.

Речь идёт о предметной области, поэтому вы можете завести своё исключение для таких ситуаций, и назвать его, например, `EntityNotFoundException`.

Последняя грань: где обрабатывать исключение? В каждом методе контроллера слишком накладно. Поскольку ситуации здесь однотипные и предсказуемые, такие исключение лучше обрабатывать в одном месте. ASP.NET позволяет вам написать свой [обработчик необработанных исключений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/processing-unhandled-exceptions-cs).

Проверьте тип исключения. Если это `EntityNotFoundException` устанавливайте статус 404, в противном случае статус 400. Для каких-то отдельных исключений или их параметров можно устанавливать статусы 403, 406, 409, 500 и так далее.

В результате получатся такие методы:

**Репозиторий**

```
public class UserRepository
{
    public async Task<User> GetUserAsync(int id)
    {
        var userDto = await dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        if (userDto == null)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("User not found.");

        return new User(userDto);
    }
}
```

**Контроллер**

```
public class UserController
{
    public async Task<UserModel> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        var user = await userRepository.GetAsync(id);

        return mapper.MapToModel(user);
    }
}
```

Наконец, **глобальный обработчик ошибок**

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError(); 

    if (exception.GetType() == typeof(EntityNotFoundException))
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
    else
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
}
```